# How can I update one field of an array when given another array containing the state of the field to update?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable containing an array of answers looking like this:

```
var answers = [
   {"answerId":5,"text":"<p>xx</p>","correct":null,"response":true},
   {"answerId":6,"text":"<p>yy</p>","correct":null,"response":false},
   {"answerId":7,"text":"<p>zz</p>","correct":null,"response":false},
   {"answerId":8,"text":"<p>aa</p>","correct":null,"response":false},
   {"answerId":9,"text":"<p>bb</p>","correct":null,"response":false},
   {"answerId":21,"text":"<p>cc</p>","correct":null,"response":false}];
```

and another variable containing an array of responses:

```
var reply = [
   {"answerId":5,"correct":true},
   {"answerId":6,"correct":false},
   {"answerId":7,"correct":false},
   {"answerId":8,"correct":false},
   {"answerId":9,"correct":false},
   {"answerId":21,"correct":false}];
```

How can I update the answers variable with the correct responses for each answerId ? So that the null's are replaced?

Comment: Did you forget the array brackets :)?

Comment: Yeah sorry but I was not really sure how to show an array. Just did my best :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we know that the indexes and answers are the same (otherwise we can sort them). A simple [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop can handle this.

```
for(var i=0;i<answers.length;i++){
    answers[i].correct = reply[i].correct;
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UuCpZ/)